# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2+\sin n)^n}{3^n n^a}$ for $a\in(0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

*This is inspired by this [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317415/is-this-series-convergent-sum-n-1-infty-frac2-31-3-cdot-sinnnn), for $a=1$.*

Borwein, Bailey, and Girgensohn pose in their book ([1,Problem 35]) as an open problem the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2+\sin n)^n}{3^n n}$$
This was solved in 2005 by Ravi B. Boppana, who put a preprint on arXiv with the solution in 2020 [2]. The solution is based on dividing this series in two, to handle separately the contribution of (1) the "tame" $n$'s for which $\sin n$ is bounded away from $1$ (by a gap at least $1/\sqrt{n}$) and (2) the "wild" ones, which can be very arbitrarily close to $1$, but that the proof shows are sparse enough that the sum of their reciprocals converges. Crucially, the argument for this second case relies on a bound on the irrationality measure $\mu(\pi)$ of $\pi$: $\mu(\pi) \leq 20$ suffices.

If I am not mistaken, even assuming $\mu(\pi)=2$ (the best possible) this proof technique, balancing the parameters, would break for $a=2/3$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2+\sin n)^n}{3^n n^{2/3}}$$
(maybe worth checking, but this is what my back-of-the-envelope calculations led to). Which leads me to my question:

> Using any available techniques, what can we say about the convergence of
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2+\sin n)^n}{3^n n^a}$$
> as a function of $a\in(0,1)$?

And does the implication go the other way -- that is, does proving convergence (or divergence) for any particular $a\in(0,1)$ imply an upper or lower bound on $\mu(\pi)$?

---

[1] Jonathan M. Borwein, David H. Bailey, and Roland Girgensohn. *Experimentation in Mathematics: Computational Paths to Discovery*. CRC
Press, 2004.

[2] Ravi B. Boppana. *Convergence of a sinusoidal infinite series from Borwein, Bailey, and Girgensohn*. 2020. [arXiv:2007.11017](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11017)

Comment: I found just amazing that beauty and truth keep following any time from apparently standard problems in mathematics, so +1.